# Label Indefinida Gráfico com Flot e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, flot

Usando o Flot para gerar os gráficos no formato pie, o gráfico é gerado com os valores em percentual, mas os labels são exibidos com 'undefined'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chartError = function(req, status, err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ', status, err);
    };

    function chartDataReceived(data) {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 1,
                    label: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 1,
                        formatter: function(label, series) {
                            return '<div style="font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
                        },
                        background: {
                            opacity: 0.8,
                            color: '#444'
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: chartDataReceived,
        error: chartError
    });
});
```

Meu select

```
SELECT tipo,status,valor, SUM(valor) AS valor_conta_tipo, caixa.tipo AS tipo_conta, caixa.status AS status_conta from caixa where caixa.status=1 GROUP BY tipo_conta
```

Arquivo **data.php** (a coluna 'tipo_conta_nome' tem valor)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dataset1[] = array($row['tipo_conta_nome'],$row['valor_conta_tipo']);
}

print json_encode($dataset1);
```

Comment: Modifiquei minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

No seu `SELECT` não existe nenhuma coluna chamada `tipo_conta_nome`, então realmente nunca vai aparecer nada com essa coluna.

Altere seu `SELECT` para retornar alguma coluna com o nome `tipo_conta_nome` ou então modifique o `$row['']` para a coluna correta.

Comment: Tentei com o código que enviou, mas, seguindo os padrões do plugin, em seus próprios exemplos são usados os códigos que uso, o problema é que não consigo localizar os valores do label em texto, ou seja, são exibidos os valores da coluna '$row['valor_conta_tipo']'  e exibido undefined para o outro.

Comment: Meu sql está `SELECT tipo,status,valor,
    SUM(valor) AS valor_conta_tipo,
    caixa.tipo AS tipo_conta,
    caixa.status AS status_conta
from caixa
where
  caixa.status=1
GROUP BY tipo_conta`

Comment: Então seu problema está ai @sNniffer, você não tem um parâmetro chamado `tipo_conta_nome`.

Comment: o `tipo_conta_nome` é pra ser o `tipo_conta` ou outro campo que você esqueceu no `SELECT`?

Comment: ô Maicon de fato, está faltando a coluna, é que informei um sql antigo, o que estou usando é: `SELECT tipo,status,valor,
                SUM(valor) AS valor_conta_tipo,
                caixa.tipo AS tipo_conta,
                caixa.status AS status_conta,
                IF(caixa.tipo = '1', 'Receita','Despesa') AS tipo_conta_nome
            from caixa
           where
              caixa.status=1
            GROUP BY tipo_conta`

Comment: @sNniffer coloca um `console.log(data)` na hora que você vai criar o `$.plot` e informa o que está mostrando